# Does Python Pandas merge (and join) fail to rename columns by suffix argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am sequentially merging some data frames by a key column, but I found that the columns aren't being renamed as expected with the suffix argument. I'm using Python 3.5 and Panadas 0.19.2.

```
import pandas as pd
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_num': ['01', '02', '03'], 'vals': ['A2', 'A3', 'A6']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_num': ['01', '02', '03'], 'vals': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_num': ['01', '02', '03'], 'vals': ['C2', 'C3', 'C6']})

df_01 = pd.merge(df0, df1, on="serial_num", suffixes=("_df0","_df1"), copy=True)
print(df_01.columns)
df_012 = pd.merge(df_01, df2, on="serial_num", suffixes=("_foobar","_df2"), copy=True)
print(df_012.columns)
```

The result is:

```
Index(['serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1'], dtype='object')
Index(['serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1', 'vals'], dtype='object')
```

This is odd because the [Pandas documentation on merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) doesn't suggest, that this should be the result. The expected result of `print(df_012.columns)` is `Index(['serial_num', 'vals_df0_foobar', 'vals_df1_foobar', 'vals_df2'], dtype='object')`. It does look like the data results are correct. I tried several things including `copy = True`, `copy.deepcopy(merged_df)`, and `copy.deepcopy(merged_df)`. Using join (`df_01 = df0.join(df1, on="serial_num", lsuffix="_df0", rsuffix="_df1"`) gives similar results. And it gets stranger, sequential merges eventually do rename the columns:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_num': ['01', '02', '03'], 'vals': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6']})
df_0123 = pd.merge(df_012, df3, on="serial_num", suffixes=("","_df3"), copy=True)
print(df_0123.columns)
df_01230 = pd.merge(df_0123, df1, on="serial_num", suffixes=("_foo","_bar"), copy=True)
print(df_01230.columns)
```

Returns:

```
Index(['serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1', 'vals', 'vals_df3'], dtype='object')
Index(['serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1', 'vals_foo', 'vals_df3',
   'vals_bar'],
  dtype='object')
```

If you followed all of that are you as surprised as me that merge suddenly renamed vals to vals_foo? Is Pandas failing to rename columns by the suffix argument in every other call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `suffixes` argument is used only to distinguish names that are shared but which we're not merging on.  As the documentation explains:

> suffixes : 2-length sequence (tuple, list, ...)
>       Suffix to apply to overlapping column names in the left and right
>       side, respectively

The key word here is *overlapping*.

When you merge `df0` and `df1` on `serial_num`, each frame has a `vals`,  which become `vals_df0` and `vals_df1` because of the suffixes.

Then you merge a frame with columns `['serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1']` with one which has `['serial_num', 'vals']`.  `vals` doesn't exist in both, so there's no need to use any suffix to distinguish it, and we get `['serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1', 'vals']`.

If you want a suffix to be applied to every non-shared column, you'll have to do it manually-- that's not what the `suffixes` argument is for.

Comment: Oh, very clear now! So the answer is yes though, pandas "fails" to rename the column, but in a very reasonable and precise way.  It just means that sequentially merging data frames with identical column names will require renaming some columns manually in the end. It would be nice to have a flag to force column renames. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Suffixes keyword is only used in case the merged dataframe has columns with same name, it ensures that each column has unique name. 
In your second merge, you are merging df01 with columns 'serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1' and df2 with columns 'serial_num', 'val'. 
You don't have any duplicate column names except 'serial_no' on which you are merging so you end up getting 'serial_num', 'vals_df0', 'vals_df1', 'vals'

Answer (score 1):

When using `join`, you can leave lsuffix empty until the final join, so that all the joins result in name collision, thus renaming the columns of the right-hand DataFrame.